# App:build and Themed folders

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I ran into some problems, after setting custom paths for additional paths I experienced some problems as soon as I added a folder into the themed directory.

The views in the additional paths are not overriding the ones from the default path and theme folders added in the additional Themed path would try to load the wrong css.

My current structure:

```
- App (Custom paths)
-- Controller
-- Model
-- Plugin
-- View
--- Themed
---- Admin *
- Swish (Actual APP directory)
- ...
```

*This directory would cause the layout to be rendered with the wrong css location: eg `css/style.css` instead of `/theme/Admin/css/style.css`

The Admin folder breaks the layout CSS and JS paths, also the views in `App/View/Themed/Admin/*` are not overriding the ones in `Swish/View/Themed/Admin/*`

Basically what I'm trying to do is have a default app where i can use the additional path for custom things I might add, things I need to change in a single project, etc..

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious if your in-app theme is colliding with the additional-path theme because they're  both called "Admin".

There are a few things you could check.

1. The `App` class allows you to print out the paths it is using to find various classes:
   `App::path('View')` shows all the paths that it would use to find Views, for instance.
2. There's a special one for finding Themes too. In the words from the API:

> `App::themePath('purple')` would give the full path to the purple
>   theme.

http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/app#line-341

This suggests to me that it will only return one path to a Theme with a given name, and might be the cause of your problems with additional class paths.

Comment: The problem is cake trying to load the css in the webroot of the themed folders in the additional path, I assumed it would load the ones from the actual app directory if the css didn't exist in the additional paths - just like it would with the view, controllers, etc. Dragging the whole webroot over to the additional paths worked but it's not the solution i'm looking for. However, I need to make it custom anyway to combine css and js files, so I can just do the checks there instead. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check folder/directory permissions ... then ...

Are you using Cakephp 2? It looks like you might be. I am actually developing an app with a themed dir for Admin, located at /app/View/Themed/Admin. To include the CSS file(s), I am using the html helper, so include them like so:

```
echo $this->Html->css('admin.main');
```

And this is called from an element located within `/app/View/Themed/Admin/elements`, and the CSS file is located in `/app/View/Themed/Admin/webroot/css`. Is this your current setup? I know this only really deals with the first issue in your post. As for your second point, could this possibly be an htaccess issue? As far as I am aware, all application specific files need to be located within /app (ie: `/home/user/htdocs/app`), while, in order to share the Cake libs, plugins, vendors etc across multiple apps, the non /app dirs can be placed above the doc root ie `/home/user/lib`, `/home/user/plugins`,`/home/user/vendors`.

Hope some of this helps.

D

Comment: This didn't solve my question but it lead me to the conclusion that the themed folders in additional paths require a copy of the full webroot from the themed folder in the app directory. Kind of stupid. It was trying to get the css from the App/View/Themed/Admin/webroot/css, and because it didn't exist there it would try getting it from Swish/webroot/css instead of Swish/View/Themed/Admin/webroot/css. CakePHP bug?